# How do I install Chrome on a brand new Windows Asus Laptop?

Tags: google-chrome, installation

I already have Chrome installed on my desktop. Is it possible to transfer copy this and paste?

Comment: Install Chrome on the new laptop, copy the old Chrome user profile, and transfer the profile to the new laptop.  It is as simply as a copy and paste procedure.

Answer (score -1):

If it's brand new like you say it should install very easily from this page.

https://www.google.ca/chrome/browser/desktop/

1. Download
2. Install
3. Run Chrome

**Bonus:** Sign into Chrome with your Google account on both browsers and all your settings get transferred over.